# How to hide bar behind status bar in Ionic app?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, statusbar, ionic-view

I am attempting to remove the opaque bar between the status bar and my app's content using the [`cordova-plugin-statusbar`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/) for Ionic. This does not seem to be part of the status bar because it is visible even when the status bar is not.

I believe this issue may have something to do with the lack of an `<ion-header>` element but I am note sure. Furthermore, I have not had this issue in my other non-Ionic Cordova projects.

Here is my `$ ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

I have tried the following status bar configurations:

#### Default

```
this.statusBar.styleDefault();
```

[image: statusBar.styleDefault()]

#### Hidden

```
this.statusBar.hide();
```

[image: statusBar.hide()]

#### Light Content

```
this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
```

[image: statusBar.styleLightContent()]

#### Light Content & No Overlay

```
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
```

[image: statusBar.styleLightContent() & statusBar.overlaysWebView(false)]

Comment: This issue does not occur when building the app in Xcode, only when viewing in the Ionic View app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with the [Ionic View app on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ionic-view/id849930087?mt=8). The preview app adds a translucent `20px` tall element that cannot be removed with the [Status Bar plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/) or CSS.

Documented in the Ionic View app's [Github issues](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues/197) and the [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-hide-bar-behind-status-bar/88270).